# Sql server Trigger insert value into one table from two difference tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables `tbl_Users`, `tbl_prepaid`, and `tbl_Expire`.

I am using a trigger on `tbl_Prepaid` that deletes the card number from `tbl_Prepaid` and inserts it into `tbl_Expire` immediately after entry.

Now I want to move `userID` from `tbl_Users` into `tbl_Expire` in the same trigger.

How I can do it?

Here is what I have so far:

```
alter TRIGGER trgAfterUpdate ON [dbo].[tbl_Prepaid] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    declare @id_ppaid int;
    declare @serial nvarchar(100);
    declare @balance nvarchar(100);
    declare @price int;



    select @id_ppaid=i.id from inserted i;  
    select @serial=i.serial from inserted i;    
    select @balance=i.balance from inserted i;  
    select @price=i.price from inserted i;


    if update(used)

    insert into tbl_Expire(id_Pripaid,serial,balance,price) 
    values(@id_ppaid,@serial,@balance,@price);


     delete from tbl_Prepaid where id=@id_ppaid;

    PRINT 'After updates trigger fired.'
GO
```

Comment: What happens if the update that fires this trigger affects more than one row? Uh-oh.

Comment: Also, how do you expect us to know which user belongs to the row(s) you are moving from `tbl_Prepaid`?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand I have session["UserID"] value in my web site for example userid equal 2 or 3 any number depend user id :)

Comment: Your trigger can't see your session variable on your web site - you need to make it visible to SQL Server. My suggestion is to use a stored procedure to perform the update, instead of relying on a trigger, and pass the user id into the stored procedure.

Comment: thanks you right must be I use stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Just fetch the value of userid in a variable from the required table, and add the variable(@userid) in your insert statement:

```
Declare @userid int
Select @userid=userid from tablename
insert into tbl_Expire(id_Pripaid,serial,balance,price,userid) 
values(@id_ppaid,@serial,@balance,@price,@userid);
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem is when an user login into owner account then add card number then press the submit button I want to pass ID value into this trigger I need using stored procedure but how I can do id ?